# Delete File in VM Server through SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2014

I tried to delete a file in `VM Server` by using a SQL Server shell command.

Like:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'DEL \\DEV-ServerName\c$\TestFileToDelete\test.txt`
```

Then a get the message:

> Access is denied

Please someone can help? This work well with my Windows command prompt

Comment: Make sure your SQL Server Service account has `"Full Control"` on folder `"TestFileToDelete"`

Answer (score 0):

1.) **share** "testFileToDelete" with SQL Server Service
2.) Run this: **EXEC xp_cmdshell 'DEL \DEV-ServerName\TestFileToDelete\test.txt`**